# Connections are active on Postgresql Database even after Program is executed

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I run my python code that reads PostGresql database to read configuration from a table.  I am using sqlalchemy engine.connect to establish the connection.  I am closing the connection using conn.close() command.  But still my Database is showing active database connections.

```
def get_postgres_data_df(self, table_name):
    global read_conn
    result_df = pd.DataFrame()
    if self.debug:
        print('Inside PostgreSQLOperations Class get_postgres_data_df method')

    connection_string = 'postgresql://' + \
                        self.user + ':' + \
                        self.password + '@' + \
                        self.host + ':' + \
                        self.port + '/' + \
                        self.database
    try:
        if self.debug:
            print('Trying to read from table {0}'.format(table_name))
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connection_string)

        read_conn = engine.connect()
        print('Connected to database @ ' + self.database)

        if self.debug:
            print(engine.table_names())

    except Exception as e:
        print('Failed to establish the connection', e)
        read_conn.close()
    query = ('SELECT * FROM ' + table_name)

    try:
        result_df = pd.read_sql(sql=query, con=read_conn)
        if self.debug:
            print('Read success for table # ', table_name)
            print(result_df)
        read_conn.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Read failed # ', e)
        read_conn.close()
    return result_df
```

Comment: Can you post how you are checking open connections? What method are you checking for open connections? Are there any possibility the open connection be the current connection you are connected to check for open connections?

Comment: @Danizavtz I am checking Open Connections using below query.                      
"select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'databasename'"

Comment: You can edit the question for include information